# I am trying to generate hal using hidl-gen tool from this http://devarea.com/android-hidl-and-project-treble/#.XJyyf0PhVuQ

Tags: android-source, hal

make hidl-gen -j64
build/core/binary.mk:925: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libv8_intermediates/src/base/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o'
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory`.'
ninja: error: unknown target 'hidl-gen', did you mean 'idegen'?
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

Comment: what is your android version

Comment: android_7.1.1_r4

Answer (score 1):

HIDL is supported from Android 8